# PyGtk3, ToggleButton, "toggled-or-untoggled" event

Tags: python, pygtk

i know **"toggled-or-untoggled"** event is not exist but i need to use event like this. is there a event to do task when button is "toggled" and "untoggled". i don't want use "clicked" event because ToggleButton can be toggled or untoggled without clicked
Thanks

example

```
def foo(obj):
    if obj.get_active():
        print("toggled")
    else:
        print("untoggled")

mybtn = gtk.ToggleButton()
mybtn.connect("toggled-or-untoggled", foo)
```

Comment: Your question should mention which version of GTK you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short GTK2+ / PyGTK demo; it should be easy enough to adapt to GTK3, if necessary.

The GUI contains a ToggleButton and a plain Button. The ToggleButton's callback just prints the state of the button whenever it's toggled, either by the user clicking on it or by other code calling its `set_active` method. The plain Button prints a message when it's clicked, and it also toggles the ToggleButton.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from __future__ import print_function
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        win.connect("destroy", lambda w: gtk.main_quit())

        box = gtk.HBox()
        box.show()
        win.add(box)

        self.togglebutton = button = gtk.ToggleButton('toggle')
        button.connect("toggled", self.togglebutton_cb)
        box.pack_start(button, expand=True, fill=False)
        button.show()

        button = gtk.Button('plain')
        button.connect("clicked", self.button_cb)
        box.pack_start(button, expand=True, fill=True)
        button.show()

        win.show()
        gtk.main()

    def button_cb(self, widget):
        s = "%s button pressed" % widget.get_label()
        print(s)
        print('Toggling...')
        tb = self.togglebutton
        state = tb.get_active()
        tb.set_active(not state)

    def togglebutton_cb(self, widget):
        state = widget.get_active()
        s = "%s button toggled to %s" % (widget.get_label(), ("off", "on")[state])
        print(s)

Test()
```

**typical output**

```
toggle button toggled to on
toggle button toggled to off
plain button pressed
Toggling...
toggle button toggled to on
plain button pressed
Toggling...
toggle button toggled to off
plain button pressed
Toggling...
toggle button toggled to on
toggle button toggled to off
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the docs](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/button_widgets.html#togglebutton) -

> When the state of the button is changed, the “toggled” signal is
>   emitted.

So, ideally, `mybtn.connect("toggled", foo)` should work.

Comment: Oh ok, then kindly elaborate more on the exact requirement.

Comment: "toggled" event runs only when widget is toggled but don't run when widget is untoggled. i want to run when widget is toggled and untoggled

Comment: @PyGtk3 The `foo` callback will be called whenever `mybtn` is toggled, whether that happens by the user clicking it or by code calling `mybtn.set_active`. So if this answer doesn't work with your code we need to see more of your code (preferably in the form of a [mcve]) so we can diagnose the real problem.

Comment: if i can print all existing event name of widgets, i can find what i want. do you know ?

Comment: @PyGtk3 You can find that info in the [Python GTK docs](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtktogglebutton.html#signal-gtktogglebutton--toggled). Also see the Signals from the objects that `ToggleButton` is a descendant of, in particular `Button` and `Widget`. But I'm pretty sure you just need to use "toggled".

Comment: thanks your answer. it works but i can't accept two answer so i upvoted it